# Why does shared_ptr have a move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, language-lawyer

In C++11 `std::shared_ptr` has a move constructor and move assignment operator.

Is there a reason why this is needed, i.e. would any programs using it behave differently if there were only the copy constructor and assignment operators?

It seems that the only effect of it is that the extra increment and later decrement of the reference counter is avoided.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is a **thread-safe** increment and decrement.

Comment: @MSalters: Yes, but that's a borderline cryptic comment without context: I may have the *only* alias of a shared pointer (e.g. because it's a local, automatic variable), so my usual conception of thread-safety would say that there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: @Arunmu: Not a duplicate, this is about a design rationale. (We could probably dig up the actual proposal, so it's not subjective, but it's not really controversial. Note that Kerrek SB and I both came up with essentially the same response withing 3 minutes of the question being asked)

Comment: @MSalters I really dont mind removing the dupe flag but the linked answer does hint (explicitly) on the optimization benefit.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Copying a shared pointer is very expensive, since the internal reference counts need to be modified atomically and with the correct memory ordering, which may incur bus locks and fences. (Recall that multiple threads may have be copying their own, local shared pointers that own the same object.) When you actually want to *transfer* ownership away from one and into another object, none of this is needed, and moving is superior.